# Giving matlab code sudo permissions? Unconnectable-connected ftp port

Tags: matlab, ftp, wget, sudo, ftplib

I'm trying to use this code to pull a bunch of data from the ModelNet data base located at vision.cs.princeton.edu I'm using the already written matlab code from the website itself; however, I'm encountering permissions errors whenever I run the code because wget (which the code uses) is located in a restricted directory in the server. Normally I would  just use sudo; however, I can't seem to run sudo matlab as a command. My question is does anybody know a way to remotely run matlab code from a server and somehow give it permissions that sudo normally would give? Also, could someone try ftping to vision.cs.princeton.edu at port 80? For some reason I'm able to connect to that port, but the connection seems to be closed and I can't ping that address either I get 100% package loss.

Thanks

Comment: There is definitely no FTP running on Port 80, its either HTTP on port 80 or FTP on some other port (probably 21).

Answer (score 0):

Use `urlread` instead of `wget`, this should fix your issues.

Comment: I am using urlread; however, the urlread seams to be calling wget